# The -jai sentence ending particle

Tags: colloquial-language, dialects, sentence-final-particles

I'm not sure if I'm just imagining things or if I remembered things wrong,

but is there some kind of colloquial dialect where sentences end in "-jai?"

Answer (score 4):

You are not imagining things.  (The tougher) Kansai male speakers do say 「～～～じゃい!」 in colloquial speech.  Only the 「い」part is a particle -- an emphatic sentence or phrase ender.  And じゃ　＝　だ.

The Standard counterpart would be だよ or だい.

The Kanto countepart would be だい or でぇ.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that だい in Tokyo is primarily used in questions?

Comment: No, you are not wrong. It is also used for strong assertion.

Comment: Have never heard `じゃい` in Kansai.  Although in all my time, I only heard `おおきに` by an お婆ちゃん exactly once.